# Is it possible to make MessageHeaders.ID not transient in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-amqp

I am attempting to send messages via a Spring Cloud Stream Source. The application receiving the message to requires the `id` header to be present. I am unable to change this requirement, so I need to find a way to ensure that the `id` header is mapped to my outgoing message.

I noticed that the `id` header was being mapped to a `message_id` property. After a bit more digging I realised that it is because the `id` header is declared as transient [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/3eedda6c9d4acf2bb762bd543f5992916c52075e/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mapping/AbstractHeaderMapper.java#L72).

Is there a way to ensure that the `id` header persists when the message is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve this using Spring Cloud Stream. Instead I reverted to using Spring AMQP.

Here is my solution:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class ExampleService {

    String exchange = "exchangeName";
    String queue = "queueName";

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void sendMessage() {
            final var jsonToQueue = "{\"message\":\"test message\"}";
            final var message = MessageBuilder.withBody(jsonToQueue.getBytes())
                    .setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)
                    .setHeader("id", UUID.randomUUID())
                    .build();
            rabbitTemplate.send(exchange, queue, message);
    }
```